# How to get a variable in Thymeleaf when a map is already involved?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

In my project I have a SVG-graph (I hope that is the right word), in which I display data from a hash map. To make this more dynamic I need a single variable for my calculation.

In this case I need help to to change the 2020 to a variable year which I set in the Java back end. But how it can get there?

```
<circle th:each="einnahmenUmsatz : ${plotDatenEinnahmen}" 
        th:cx="${100*einnahmenUmsatz.getKey().getMonthValue() + 1200*(einnahmenUmsatz.getKey().getYear()%2020)}" 
        th:cy="${375-20*einnahmenUmsatz.getValue().getNumber().intValue()/1000}" 
        th:data-value="${einnahmenUmsatz.getValue().getNumber().intValue()}" r="4">
    <title th:text="${einnahmenUmsatz.getValue()}"></title>
</circle>
```

Comment: Why you cannot just use another attribute for the year? One option if it *must* be a single object would be to change `plotDatenEinnahmen` to be an object where you can `getEinnahmenUmsatzElements()` and `getYear()` . It would be interesting to know why you are using the modulo operator together with the year.

Comment: The modulo to calculate the current year. If mod = 0 the year is still the same as the beginning, 1 = 2021 and so on. This might be complicated and not the best way, but it works.
Yes, but how can I get the atribute to my calculation? (Sorry I'm new to thymeleaf and my ideas often don't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another attribute to the `Model` (when using Spring) or another variable to the `Context` (when using plain Thymeleaf):

```java
model.addAttribute("year", 2020); // Spring Web/MVC
// or
context.addVariable("year", 2020); // plain Thymeleaf
```

And then use it in the template (replace `%` with `-`):

```
th:cx="${100*einnahmenUmsatz.getKey().getMonthValue() + 1200*(einnahmenUmsatz.getKey().getYear()-year)}"
```

---

*Full working example with Spring (slightly modified):*

```
@Controller
public class GraphicsController {

    @GetMapping("/graphics")
    public String getGraphics(Model model) {

        // generate test data
        final Map<YearAndMonth, Integer> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
                data.put(new YearAndMonth(2019+y, m), 6000 + (6*y + m) * 1000);
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute("data", data);
        model.addAttribute("year", 2020);
        return "graphics";
    }

    public static class YearAndMonth {
        private final int year;
        private final int month;

        public YearAndMonth(final int year, final int month) {
            this.month = month;
            this.year = year;
        }

        public int getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public int getMonth() {
            return month;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SVG with Thymeleaf</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg viewBox="-1200 -400 3800 800">
  <circle th:each="entry : ${data}"
          th:cx="${100*entry.getKey().getMonth() + 1200*(entry.getKey().getYear()-year)}"
          th:cy="${375-20*entry.getValue()/1000}"
          th:data-value="${entry.getValue()}"
          r="4">
    <title th:text="${entry.getValue()}"></title>
  </circle>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output in browser]

Comment: Thank you very much, that really solves the problem. I thought I had to insert the variable at th: each (I don't know why).

Felix